# Undefined reference to err_exit ,berr_exit..etc in openssl socket programming in ubuntu

Tags: sockets, ubuntu, openssl, header-files

This is my first **openssl**  **socket** program

refer this [link](http://www.rtfm.com/openssl-examples/)

First I compile with  **gcc -g server.c -o server**

but gets  this error

> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../crt1.o: In function `_start':
>   (.text+0x18): undefined reference to`main'
>   /tmp/ccxiY18C.o: In function `tcp_listen':
>   /home/usr/Desktop/c-examples/server.c:11: undefined reference to`err_exit'
>   /home/usr/Desktop/c-examples/server.c:20: undefined reference to `berr_exit'
>   /tmp/ccxiY18C.o: In function`load_dh_params':
>   /home/usr/Desktop/c-examples/server.c:33: undefined reference to `BIO_new_file'
>   /home/usr/Desktop/c-examples/server.c:34: undefined reference to`berr_exit'
>   /home/usr/Desktop/c-examples/server.c:36: undefined reference to `PEM_read_bio_DHparams'
>   /home/usr/Desktop/c-examples/server.c:37: undefined reference to`BIO_free'
>   /home/usr/Desktop/c-examples/server.c:38: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_ctrl'
>   /home/usr/Desktop/c-examples/server.c:39: undefined reference to`berr_exit'
>   /tmp/ccxiY18C.o: In function `generate_eph_rsa_key':
>   /home/usr/Desktop/c-examples/server.c:47: undefined reference to`RSA_generate_key'
>   /home/usr/Desktop/c-examples/server.c:49: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_ctrl'
>   /home/usr/Desktop/c-examples/server.c:50: undefined reference to`berr_exit'
>   /home/usr/Desktop/c-examples/server.c:52: undefined reference to `RSA_free'

then  i compile it with  **gcc -g server.c -o server -lssl -lcrypt**

It gives

> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../crt1.o: In function `_start':
>   (.text+0x18): undefined reference to`main'
>   /tmp/ccPlisKL.o: In function `tcp_listen':
>   /home/usr/Desktop/c-examples/server.c:11: undefined reference to`err_exit'
>   /home/usr/Desktop/c-examples/server.c:20: undefined reference to `berr_exit'
>   /tmp/ccPlisKL.o: In function`load_dh_params':
>   /home/usr/Desktop/c-examples/server.c:34: undefined reference to `berr_exit'
>   /home/usr/Desktop/c-examples/server.c:39: undefined reference to`berr_exit'
>   /tmp/ccPlisKL.o: In function `generate_eph_rsa_key':
>   /home/usr/Desktop/c-examples/server.c:50: undefined reference to`berr_exit'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

How can i overcome this problem .. please give me a solution..

Answer (score 1):

It's `-lcrypto`, not `-lcrypt`. Just add the `o`